# how to clear image variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have  the following UI :
[image]

I m checking image resolution on each of the image to be uploaded when they get changed.

```
 //preview image
    $(document).on('change', '#product_image', function(event) {  
        var output = document.getElementById('preview_product_image');
        output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]); 

         image_check(output,event);

    });
    //image1
    $(document).on('change', '#product_image1', function(event) {
        var output = document.getElementById('preview_product_image1');
        output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);

        image_check(output,event);

    });
```

//the resolution check code below

```
 var loaded = false;
    function loadHandler(path,width,height) {

        if (loaded) {
            return;
        }

        loaded = true;

        alert("The image you have selected is low resloution image.Your image width="+width+",Heigh="+height+". Please select image greater or equal to 600x600,Thanks!");

        var output = document.getElementById(path);


        output.src = "http://localhost/uploads/no-photo.jpg";
    }

    function image_check(output,event) {
         //alert("Image size");

        var output = document.getElementById("preview_product_image");
        output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
        var img = new Image();
        img = output;

         img.onload = function() {

           var width = img.naturalWidth,
           height = img.naturalHeight;

            //window.URL.revokeObjectURL( img.src );

            if( width < 600 || height < 600  ) {
               // alert("The image you have selected is low resloution image.Your image width="+width+",Heigh="+height+". Please select image greater or equal to 255x255,Thanks!");
                 if(img.complete) {
                    loadHandler("preview_product_image",width,height);
                }
            }
        };   
}
```

**THE PROBLEM IS IT only check for one of them when loaded at first time , later it would not validate for other image preview box  .
Please help ?**

Comment: You are using ID attributes instead of classes. ID's should be used only once.

Comment: maybe because there are two functions being called `image_check` and `image_check_1` and the second one does not exist. check our console for errors.

Comment: i though memory or effect of shared variable and that why i maje them two functions

Comment: Also avoid using so many hardcoded ids in JS code. make it more flexible with either class names or data attributes.

Comment: yes sir , i was tired of being testing it was added for tracing the bug ,okay

Comment: loaded variable is declared outside of the function scope. try declaring it inside of image_check or any other controlled scope for a single execution. in this scenario it is going to retain it's value unless overridden somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has solved the situation , Thanks to all !!

```
 var output = document.getElementById('preview_product_image');


        if(this.height < 600 || this.width < 600) {
          output.src = "http://localhost/danieladenew/uploads/no-photo.jpg";
           alert("The image you have selected is low resloution image.Your image width="+this.width+",Heigh="+this.height+". Please select image greater or equal to 600x600,Thanks!");
        }
        else{
           output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);

         }
         return;

        }

        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
```